# Server edition - Nothing appears when password is entered

Tags: server, login

I'm new to the OS and need some help. 
So I installed Ubuntu server, after solving a lot of problems I'm stuck on the login page.
So I have:
(system name) login:

I remember setting up something and named it:destiny-user and when I get to the password something weird happens. I can't enter anything unless I press enter and go to the next line?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Passwords are not shown in a terminal session when entering it on the password. Are you sure this is not the intended behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

The password line will not display the password you type in. Once you type in you user name and click enter, it moves to the password line. Anything you type here will not display (not in letters or asterisks).

Comment: This is to improve security: someone looking over your shoulder cannot even see how long your password is!  ;-)